# Defining boost msm state machine with more than 50 rows

Tags: c++, boost

I have state machine where I have about 60 rows (transitions). It is not compiling anymore because there of some limitation on MPL types.

I found out from the Boost MSM documentation that this limitation can be solved by

> For the moment, the only solution to achieve more is to add headers
>   to the MPL (luckily, this is not very complicated).

so how add headers to the MPL?

Comment: Found solution, in boost libraries folder there are mpl and vector folders. To be able to create state machine with more that 50 rows, you must add new header files to this folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before any `#include <mpl...>` define this :

```
#define BOOST_MPL_CFG_NO_PREPROCESSED_HEADERS
#define BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE 30 // or whatever you need               
#define BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_MAP_SIZE 30 // or whatever you need
```

Comment: By this way you can create maximum 50 rows, because of MPL types limitation. By defining own header files you can create even 60 rows.

Comment: From the boost msm documentation `The other limitation is that the MPL types are defined only up to 50 entries. For the moment, the only solution to achieve more is to add headers to the MPL (luckily, this is not very complicated).`

Comment: Editing the `#define`s only works up to 50 transitions max. Anything above that, you need to add some headers.